# How to remove duplicate values from huge datasets using python

Tags: python

I want to remove duplicate values from large dataset. Please help me to remove it

```
names = [ ["john","is","good","is"], ["shawn","is","bad"],...,
 ["john","shawn","is","are"] ]

expected output : [ ["john","is,"good"],["shawn","bad"],...,["are"] ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to remove duplicates from main list or sub lists?

Comment: What do you mean by 'huge' ? what kind of duplicates are we talking about, just words or whole sublists?

Comment: I just edited it now.I think that output may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it iteratively like so:

```
names = [ ["john","is","good","is"], ["shawn","is","bad"],["john","shawn","is","are"] ]
# Create an empty set
seen = set()
out = []
for sub in names:
    # _sub holds the words we want to keep
    _sub = []
    for word in sub:
        # Only keep words that we haven't seen
        if word not in seen:
            _sub.append(word)
        # Add all words to the set
        seen.add(word)
    out.append(_sub)

# [['john', 'is', 'good'], ['shawn', 'bad'], ['are']]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use dictionary to get unique values:

```
names = [ ["john","is","good","is"], ["shawn","is","bad"]]
dct = {}
uniqueNames = []
for n in names:
    temp = []
    for k in n:
        if k not in dct:
            temp.append(k)
            dct[k] = 1
    uniqueNames.append(temp)
print(uniqueNames)
```

output:

```
[['john', 'is', 'good'], ['shawn', 'bad']]
```

code complexity is O(n*m) [n is number of sublist and m is the number of element in each sub list] . As search in dictionay complexity is  Average: O(1)so we can ignor this

Answer (score 3):

Just to get another perspective to decide, which answer you should choose, because you mention that you are dealing with a *large* dataset:

Performance check:

```
%timeit dict_approach(names)     # Asif
%timeit set_double_loop(names)   # Alex
%timeit pure_sets(names)         # SpghttCd

1.68 µs ± 21.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
2.22 µs ± 57.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.58 µs ± 98.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

```
def dict_approach(names):   # Asif
    dct = {}
    uniqueNames = []
    for n in names:
        temp = []
        for k in n:
            if k not in dct:
                temp.append(k)
                dct[k] = 1
        uniqueNames.append(temp)
    return uniqueNames

def set_double_loop(names):   # Alex
    seen = set()
    out = []
    for sub in names:
        # _sub holds the words we want to keep
        _sub = []
        for word in sub:
            # Only keep words that we haven't seen
            if word not in seen:
                _sub.append(word)
            # Add all words to the set
            seen.add(word)
        out.append(_sub)
    return out

def pure_sets(names):   # SpghttCd
    s = set()
    result = []
    for sublist in names:
        result.append(set(sublist).difference(s))
        s = s.union(sublist)
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the order of the elements in the sublist important?
If not, you could do it completely with `set`s:

```
names = [['john', 'is', 'good', 'is'], ['shawn', 'is', 'bad'], ['john', 'shawn', 'is', 'are']]    
s = set()
result = []

for sublist in names:
    result.append(list(set(sublist).difference(s)))
    s = s.union(sublist)

# [['is', 'good', 'john'], ['bad', 'shawn'], ['are']]
```

If you could live with a list of sets instead of a list of lists you could even leave the cast to list:

```
...
result.append(set(sublist).difference(s))
...

# [{'good', 'is', 'john'}, {'bad', 'shawn'}, {'are'}]
```

Comment: You're welcome - but worked _also_ is only true for my approach. Note that @Asif's solution is the fastest presented here (see my other answer regarding performance).